# AS3 access dynamic textfield on stage from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I have this dynamic textfield on stage, and I want to access it from my xmlloader class, so it can display text from my xml file. I just can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
MovieClip(root).thetextfieldonstage.text = "yep";
```

can call the textfield from class.